# If it is impossible to have O(1) pred on CoC, then why does this work?

Tags: functional-programming, coq, agda

I always assumed it had been proven that `pred` wasn't expressible in constant time on the Calculus of Constructions for any encoding of datatypes. Now, mind this encoding for nats:

```
S0 : ∀ (r : *) . (r -> r) -> r -> r
S0 = λ s z . z

S1 : ∀ (r : *) (((∀ (r : *) . (r -> r) -> r -> r) -> a) -> (a -> a)))
S1 = λ s z . (s (λ s z . z))

S2 : (∀ (r : *) . ((∀ (r : *) . ((∀ (r : *) . (r -> r) -> r -> r) -> a) -> a -> a) -> a) -> a -> a)
S1 = λ s z . (s (λ s z . (s (λ s z . z))))
```

That's just the Scott encoding, except I'm actually typing the whole term instead of using recursion. What I noticed is, under this seemingly stupid encoding, I'm actually able to define not only Zero and Succ, but also `O(1)` Pred:

```
SNat 
    =  λ (n : Nat)
    -> (n * 
           (λ (p:*) -> (∀ (r:*) . (p -> r) -> r -> r))
           (∀ (r:*) -> (r -> r) -> r -> r))

SNat_Zero
    =  λ (r : *)
    -> λ (s : r -> r)
    -> λ (z : r)
    z

SNat_Succ
    =  λ (k : Nat)
    -> λ (n : SNat k)
    -> λ (r : *)
    -> λ (s : (SNat k) -> r)
    -> λ (z : r)
    (s n)

SNat_Pred
    =  λ (k : Nat)
    -> λ (n : SNat (Succ k))
    -> λ (n (Maybe (SNat k))
            (p:(SNat k) (Maybe_Just (SNat k) p))
            (Maybe_Nothing (SNat k)))
```

*Note: I just translated this by eye from another syntax. In case something is wrong, [this](https://github.com/MaiaVictor/calculus-of-constructions/blob/master/lib/SNat_Pred.coc) is correct. You can run it by cloning this repo and typing:*

```
cd calculus-of-constructions
npm i -g
cd lib
coc type SNat_Pred
coc norm SNat_Pred
```

**Is this possible because my implementation has some kind of bug, or was I mistaken about the existence of said proof?**

Comment: Your `SNat_Succ` doesn't use `z`. That can't be right.

Comment: Did you mean to have `S2 = ...` on the 6th line?

Comment: I also vaguely remember that there is an encoding of the natural numbers in the pure lambda calculus that does allow one to program an `O(1)` predecessor function, but I can't find a reference...

Comment: @DanielWagner How so? The Scott-encoded Succ is just `λ n s z . (s n)` so it, too, doesn't use `z`.

Comment: @ArthurAzevedoDeAmorim yes, thanks.

Comment: @dfeuer why did you remove the haskell and idris tags?

Comment: @MaiaVictor, a question about an implementation of COC in JavaScript is hardly Haskell-related. I imagine the people who follow the Coq and Agda tags are probably pretty likely to know this sort of thing, so I left those on. Idris was a judgement call, but it's not directly related and I don't think this sort of thing is really close to the main thrust of Idris R&D.

Comment: @dfeuer I see. Maybe I'm wrongly uniting those communities as one. My thought was that Morte is a Haskell project (so is Agda, actually). So, this kind of project seemed to be always showing up on Haskell-related communities and news, thus I assumed it would be relevant.

Comment: Haskell is a great language for writing compilers, so lots of compilers are written in Haskell. There is a lot of overlap and communication among these communities, but they're certainly not the same.

Comment: @dfeuer fair enough, sorry.

Comment: A question regarding this: "I always assumed it had been proven that `pred` [...]". What proof are you referring to here?

Comment: @cic I wish I knew, I hold this information from what people told me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I cannot understand very well what your encoding is trying to do. But your repository seems to have the following definitions (translated in Coq-like syntax from the files `Nat.coc` and `SNat.coc`):

```
Definition Nat :=
  forall X : *, (X -> X) -> X -> X.

Definition SNat :=
  fun n : Nat => n * (* Some more stuff *).
```

If I understand correctly, the definition of `SNat` is using the natural number `n` to iterate a function of type `* -> *`. This doesn't seem well-typed, because `n` takes as an argument something of type `*`, thus  requiring `* : *`, which is not valid in CoC.

Comment: Ah, so that was it. I indeed have `* : *`, but I didn't realize I was making use of it there. Amazing catch. Thank you.